# Embedded Systems StackExchange

Tags: discussion

The fledgling [Embedded.SE](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com) is likely to be short-lived affair, with a [proposal for it to be killed off already](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/questions/69/closing-this-site-on-friday-august-14/)

Given the significant over-lap between that site and this, I have suggested that the *Embedded Systems* site be merged into *Robotics.SE* with the combined site being renamed *Embedded Systems and Robotics*

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look at the questions on the site and [only been able to identify one](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/a/72/186), I don't think that any kind of merge would be appropriate, but we should certainly suggest (using [that answer](http://meta.embedded.stackexchange.com/a/72/186)) that any questions which are on topic here be migrated here.

Answer (score 0):

Robotics seems like a very small part of the embedded world, and the vast majority of questions here aren't what I would hope to see on an embedded site.  The proposed merge feels quite inorganic to me.